# TPL Unit Test BufferBlock LinkTo TargetBlock

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asynchronous, tpl-dataflow, bufferblock

I am trying to create unit tests for a TPL BufferBlock and want to test that an exception gets thrown. However, the test passes before the exception gets thrown.

**EDIT**

Also, this is a long running process so I do not call complete. This process runs until the app is closed

Here's the code:

```
public class PriorityMessageQueue 
{
        private BufferBlock<MyMessage> _messageBufferBlock;
        private async Task<bool> Init()
        {
            var executionDataflowBlockOptions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount,
                BoundedCapacity = 1000
            };

            var prioritizeMessageBlock = new ActionBlock<MyMessage>(msg =>
            {
                try
                {
                    SetMessagePriority(msg);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }

            });

            _messageBufferBlock = new BufferBlock<MyMessage>(executionDataflowBlockOptions);
            _messageBufferBlock.LinkTo(prioritizeMessageBlock);
        }

        public async Task<bool> EnqueueAsync(MyMessage message)
        {
            if (message == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(message), "The  message object is NULL. Cannot enqueue a NULL object.");
            }

            return await _messageBufferBlock.SendAsync(message);
        }

        private void SetMessagePriority(MyMessage message)
        {
           if (message.MessageType.Equals(MessageType.Unknown))
           {
               throw new ArgumentException("The SCBA Message Type is 'Unknown'. Cannot set the Message Priority on an 'Unknown' message type.");
           }

           switch (message.MessageType)
           {
               case MessageType.Admin:                   
                   message.MessagePriority = MessagePriority.Admin;
                   break;
               case MessageType.AuthUser:
                   message.MessagePriority = MessagePriority.High;
                   break;                
               case MessageType.UnknownUser:
                   message.MessagePriority = MessagePriority.Normal;
                   break;                
               default:
                   message.MessagePriority = MessagePriority.Normal;
                   break;
           }
        }

}
```

Here's the test code

```
    [TestClass()]
    public class PriorityMessageQueueTests
    {
        private IPriorityMessageQueue _queue;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

            var logRepository = new Mock<ILogRepository>();

            container.RegisterInstance(logRepository.Object);

            _queue = new PriorityMessageQueue(logRepository.Object);
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            _queue.Dispose();
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentNullException))]
        public async Task EnqueueTest_NullMessage()
        {
            await _queue.EnqueueAsync(null);
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public async Task EnqueueTest_UnknownMessageType()
        {
            var message = new MyMessage
            {
                Id = 1,
                Text = "Unit Test"
            };

            var result = await _queue.EnqueueAsync(message);

            Assert.AreEqual(true, result);
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public void DequeueTest()
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public void GetNextInQueue()
        {
            Assert.Fail();
        }
    }
```

The ArgumentException exception gets thrown correctly in SetMessagePriority because the 'MessageType' equals MessageType.Unknown. However, by the time ArgumentException is thrown the unit test EnqueueTest_UnknownMessageType has passed successfully because

```
var result = await _queue.EnqueueAsync(message);
```

returns 'true' before the exception gets thrown. 
How do I write the test EnqueueTest_UnknownMessageType so that it fails because the exception gets thrown?

I have tried adding

```
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
```

to the test, but it still passes

Comment: This example does not look complete. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the issue.

Comment: In general `await _queue.EnqueueAsync(message);` is not likely to throw the exception your looking for. Any exception caught and thrown within your `ActionBlock` is going to be attached to that blocks `Completion` `Task`. That's the the `Task` you'll need to `await` to observe the exception. To say more you'll need to provide an MCVE as @Nkosi pointed out.

Comment: @Nkosi this example is complete. Please tell me what you think might be missing

Comment: @Que, The implementation of the public method `EnqueueAsync()` which is being called by the unit tests is not shown.

Comment: @Eric, thanks for pointing that out I've updated the code. I had to pull out a lot of extra code in order to simplify my problem and I guess I removed that method by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JSteward pointed out, the exception that you are expecting to see won't be part of the `Task` which you are awaiting in the `EnqueueAsync()` method.

Reading through the [docs for `DataflowBlock.SendAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194681(v=vs.110).aspx) says the following about the return value:

> If the target accepts and consumes the offered element during the call to `SendAsync`, upon return from the call the resulting `Task<TResult>` will be completed and its `Result` property will return `true`. If the target declines the offered element during the call, upon return from the call the resulting `Task<TResult>` will be completed and its `Result` property will return `false`.

The `Task` only conveys that the message was received or declined by the first block. There is no mention of propagating exceptions from subsequent blocks back to the original `Task`.

If you are looking for an early validation of the message type, you could do that check right in your `EnqueueAsync()` call, removing that block from your dataflow pipeline.

Otherwise, if you want that to be a step in a larger dataflow pipeline, you could inject a [`BroadcastBlock<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160447(v=vs.110).aspx) to which you can attach the rest of the "happy path" pipeline to process the known message types as well as a block that only receives unknown message types where you can take whatever action you would like to communicate an unknown message type was received.

Comment: thanks. I had already moved the validation logic, but it's nice to know I am on the right track learning TPL Dataflow